# PHP front controller in nginx

Tags: php, regex, nginx, fastcgi, front-controller

I have a wiki that hosts user-generated content with URLs like `/wiki/view/pagename` and `/wiki/modify/pagename`. I'm using an nginx configuration that goes something like:

```
location /wiki/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wiki/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    #fastcgi stuff...
}
```

It's been working great and as far as i can tell, this is the recommended approach. However, today, a user created a page named "whatever.php", so it needs the URLs `/wiki/view/whatever.php` to be redirected to my `/wiki/index.php`... but it gets caught in the second location block and returns a 404 to the user-agent.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Can i add an extra location block to rewrite *.php to the main script somewhere in such a way that won't affect actually routing pages? I still want to use nginx to serve static content inside the `/wiki/` directory and to preserve the behaviour of everything outside this directory.

Repost of [this](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,228830) dead forum thread

Comment: You should read this: http://nginx.org/r/location and this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html